# MySQL - Concatenate 0 to all column values if no 0 to begin with

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

I'm working with a database where we have a FNN column (Full National Number). In Australia, all FNN's are 10 digits and begin with a 0 followed by the single digit state number and then the 8 digit phone number.

Currently, half the entries only have 9 digits, meaning that the first 0 is excluded, but the other half have the full 10 digits.

I want to concatenate a 0 to all column values that don't have a 0 to begin with. Here's the current query that I've attempted but it results on a 0 affected.

```
UPDATE SUBSCRIBERS SET FNN=concat('0',FNN) WHERE FNN LIKE '[1-9]%';
```

State digits do not begin with a 0, so I only need to concatenate a 0 where the first number is between 1-9. Why isn't the above query working?

Thanks.

Regards,

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question you mentioned that some of them have 9 digits while the other half have 10 digits, So I suggest instead of looking for rows that has FNN start with 1-9, why dont look for rows that has FNN = 9 digits?

```
UPDATE SUBSCRIBERS
SET FNN=concat('0',FNN)
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(FNN) = 9;
```

Comment: Good answer too, every answer here is valid and works. Thanks.

Comment: That would be quite a bit slower, because it would have to scan the table, and calculate the length of each string.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you can use `not like`:

```
UPDATE SUBSCRIBERS SET FNN=concat('0',FNN) WHERE FNN NOT LIKE '0%';
```

Comment: That's a bit more elegant that what I suggested.

Answer (score 1):

That's not quite right.

First of all, MySQL does not support the LIKE '[1-9]' character class convention.  That's a SQL Server thing.

The simplest way of doing this is pretty ugly, but it sounds like a one-time deal:

```
UPDATE Subscribers SET fnn = concat('0', fnn) WHERE fnn LIKE '1%'
UPDATE Subscribers SET fnn = concat('0', fnn) WHERE fnn LIKE '2%'
UPDATE Subscribers SET fnn = concat('0', fnn) WHERE fnn LIKE '3%'
UPDATE Subscribers SET fnn = concat('0', fnn) WHERE fnn LIKE '4%'
    <etc>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like plenty of working answers here, but you could eliminate the `WHERE` clause altogether with:

```
UPDATE SUBSCRIBERS
SET FNN = RIGHT(concat('0',FNN),10)
```